# How to choose motherboard for AMD APU

Tags: cpu, motherboard, amd-radeon, integrated-graphics

I'm a little confused when it comes to choosing an AMD APU board. To use the onboard graphics of the APU (specifically the AMD 8350), does the board need a graphic output?

Comment: What do you mean by a graphic output? Hardware? Software?

Comment: Graphic output as in HDMI, VGA, etc.

Comment: Pick the motherboard that supports the APU you wish to purchase, any motherboard that supports that socket, will work for you.  If you only want to use the APU and have no external GPU the motherboard obviously needs a graphic port/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is really just my opinion from my personal experience.

So the main things you need to think about when choosing a setup are:

1. Processor you want
2. Motherboard that works with the processor you picked and space for the amount of RAM you want. Also consider the available PCI slots for other peripheral cards (graphics, wifi, etc.)
3. If the motherboard has onboard graphics, it will already have a place to connect a monitor (VGA, DVI, HDMI). If it has nothing, you need to get a graphics card that will fit in the availble PCI slots on the motherboard you picked.

After all that you can add other peripherals, drives, and of course a power supply to power everything!